# python3 powershell stdout cyrillic encoding

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I need to do the following: I connect to the Windows server from Python via ssh and run the powershell command on it. I need to get a response from that server and use it further.
If I make a request like this:

```
command_company = (
            'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "'
            'Get-ADUser -Filter \\"sAMAccountName -like \'j.d\'\\" -Properties sAMAccountName, Mobile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mobile"'
        )
```

Then everything works for me and I get a mobile number.
If I do like this:

```
command_company = (
            'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "'
            'Get-ADUser -Filter \\"sAMAccountName -like \'j.d\'\\" -Properties sAMAccountName, Company | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Company"'
        )
```

then I don't get an error:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Get-ADUser -Filter \"sAMAccountName -like 'j.d'\" -Properties sAMAccountName, Company | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Company"
env: {}, command: powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Get-ADUser -Filter \"sAMAccountName -like 'j.d'\" -Properties sAMAccountName, Company | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Company", subsystem: None, exit_status: None, exit_signal: None, returncode: None, stdout: , stderr:
Output:
Exit Code: None
```

I'm guessing this might be an encoding issue with the response that powershell sends.
If I execute the request directly in the PS

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -like 'j.d'" -Properties sAMAccountName, Company | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Company
```

I get the answer:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\ServiceScripts\Test.ps1
ООО МерседесБенцРус
```

How to change response encoding?

Full code:

```
async def run_ssh_command(user_login):
    async with asyncssh.connect(edited) as conn:

        command_company = (
            'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "'
            'Get-ADUser -Filter \\"sAMAccountName -like \'j.d\'\\" -Properties sAMAccountName, Company | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Company"'
        )
        print(command_company)
        result = await conn.run(command_company)
        print(result)
        output_company = result.stdout
        exit_code = result.exit_status
        print(f"Output: {output_company}")
        print(f"Exit Code: {exit_code}")
        await client.send_message(chat_id, f'From: {output_company}', reply_to=reply_to_msg_id)
        return output_company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [you found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77142767/45375), by switching to a different SSH library that allows you to specify the character encoding for decoding the stdout output received explicitly.

- Let me add some background information...
- ... and offer Python v3+ solution that *may* work with your original code: I don't know how SSH factors into this (your original library, [asyncssh](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/), claims to be using UTF-8), but the sample code below definitely works with a *local* PowerShell call that uses UTF-8, as shown.

---

The **PowerShell CLI** in both editions - [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) - **encodes its stdout** output based on the **active (output) console code page, which defaults to the system's *OEM* code page**.

If you don't want to hard-code it, as in your code, you can use the following to determine it:

```py
from ctypes import windll; cp = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
```

If you want to **use UTF-8 instead** - which is a necessity if the PowerShell command outputs characters that cannot be represented in the OEM code page - you can do the following:

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from ctypes import windll

# Sample text containing an ASCII char., 
# a non-ASCII char that can be mapped onto at least some OEM code pages, 
# and one that cannot.  
text = 'e€╳' 
# A sample PowerShell command that simply echoes the text.
command = f"powershell.exe -noprofile -c '{text}'"

# Save the current console output code page and temporarily change it to
# UTF-8 (65001)
oldCp = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)

# Call the PowerShell CLI, which now emits UTF-8 text.
# Note the use of .decode(), which is based on sys.getdefaultencoding(), 
# which is UTF-8 in v3+, and the .strip() call to remove a trailing newline.
out = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode().strip()

# Restore the previous output console code page.
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(oldCp)

# Print the captured output and its byte representation.
print('received text: ' + out)
print(out.encode()) # byte representation
```

Note:

- The above only ensures that the PowerShell child process emits UTF-8 and that its output is decoded as such inside the Python process, which is unrelated to what character encoding Python *itself* uses for its output streams.
- To put Python v3.7+ itself in [Python UTF-8 Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode), which makes it decode input as UTF-8 and produce UTF-8 output, pass command-line option `-X utf8` or define environment variable `PYTHONUTF8` with a value of `1` *before* invocation.

  - (Only) if you do that, the alternative to calling `.decode()` above is to pass `text=True` as an additional argument to the `subprocess.run()` call.
  - Independently, passing `encoding='utf-8'` as an additional argument instead of calling `.decode()` is an option, too.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced ssh with paramiko, cp866 was selected as the encoding
In this version everything works:

```
async def run_ssh_command(user_login):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()

    try:
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect('Edited')

        command_company = (
            'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "'
            'Get-ADUser -Filter \'sAMAccountName -like \'\'{0}\'\'\' -Properties sAMAccountName, Company | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Company"'.format(user_login)
        )

        print(command_company)

        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command_company)

        output_company = stdout.read().decode('cp866')

        exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()

        print(f"Output: {output_company}")
        print(f"Exit Code: {exit_code}")

        return output_company

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return None

    finally:
        client.close()
```